# Config AppleWatch what to dial during "Fall Detection"?

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

I do not want "Fall Detection" to dial 911 if I were walking, fall, and all I need to do is rest. I've been running on trails, stumbled and fell to the ground. I sat there and resting. But, I think by accident the fall detection dialed emergency services.

Comment: 2 ideas to use with fall detection off: 1. Explain your situation in your “medical ID” in health app, but people may not look. 2. Keep a physical paper/laminated card etc that you can pull out and give to people with the explanation, phone numbers to call etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Source](https://www.imore.com/how-set-and-use-fall-detection-apple-watch-series-4):

Fall detection on your Apple Watch Series 4 is off by default unless you are age 65 or older.  There's no way to get Fall Detection to do what you want, it's not configurable that way.  I think your only option is to turn it off.

From [Apple's Support document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208944):

> If you've entered your age when you set up your Apple Watch or in the
>   Health app and you're age 65 and over, this feature automatically
>   turns on.

If, for any reason, you decide that you don't want Fall Detection on, you can disable it in the Watch app on your iPhone.

1. Launch the **Watch** app on your iPhone.
2. Tap the **My Watch** tab at the bottom left.
3. Tap **Emergency SOS**.
4. Scroll down and turn off **Fall Detection**.  The switch is to the left when it's off.

[image: Turn off Fall Detection]